# Lambda Edge Origin Request Trigger 502

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I'm getting started with Amazon AWS and integrating JAMStack in their system, following [their official tutorial](https://pages.awscloud.com/Deploying-JAMStack-Applications-Using-Amazon-S3-CloudFront-and-LambdaEdge_2020_0515-NET_OD.html) (which includes [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFean2aj_8I)) of a example project.

Everything went smoothly until the creation of a Lambda@Edge Function.

I just created the function and set to trigger at Origin Request from CloudFront. It's just this:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const REQUEST = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const URI = REQUEST.uri;

    return REQUEST;
};
```

When I go to the root my CloudFront domain, I get my "Hello World" from index.html, which is in a Bucket. However when I go to subpaths, like /404 or non-existing path I get 502 and not 404.html from /404 nor 404.html for non-existing pages.

The role is "Basic Lambda@Edge permissions (for CloudFront trigger)".

---

I get this:

> 502 ERROR The request could not be satisfied. The Lambda function
> result failed validation: The body is not a string, is not an object,
> or exceeds the maximum size. See Limits in the Amazon CloudFront
> Developer Guide. We can't connect to the server for this app or
> website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a
> configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website
> owner. If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can
> find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing
> the CloudFront documentation.

Comment: did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @pkyeck nope, I gave up on the cache (which was the purpose of this lambda function). I checked if: 1. I was not using alias or $latest, 2. deployed a numbered version, 3. the region was correct (this lambda is only available in us-East-1 region) and if it was using the correct role. It's still there, but disabled.

Comment: thanks a lot! have to continue looking for the error ...